# How to change a Flutter app language without restarting the app?

Tags: flutter

In the settings page of my app, I would like to add an option that controls the app language.

I can set the language before starting the app like this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // other arguments
      locale: Locale('ar'),
    );
  }
```

But is it possible to change the language without restarting the app?

Comment: Intresting, I remember on Android It's quite a hassle to change language without loosing state. But it could be done.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wrap your `MaterialApp` into a `StreamBuilder` which will be responsible for providing the `Locale` value to your application. And it will enable you to dynamically change it without restarting your app. This is an example using the [rxdart package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart) to implement the stream:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: setLocale,
      initialData: Locale('ar',''),
      builder: (context, localeSnapshot) {
        return MaterialApp(
          // other arguments
          locale: localeSnapshot.data,
        );
      }
    );
  }

  Stream<Locale> setLocale(int choice) {

    var localeSubject = BehaviorSubject<Locale>() ;

    choice == 0 ? localeSubject.sink.add( Locale('ar','') ) : localeSubject.sink.add( Locale('en','') ) ;


    return localeSubject.stream.distinct() ;

  }
```

The above demonstration is just a basic way of how to achieve what you want to, but for a proper implementation of streams in your app you should consider using app-wide BloCs, which will significantly improve the quality of your app by reducing the number of unnecessary builds.

Comment: but the streamBuilder doesnt get rebuilt when we call setLocale from other part of app

Answer (score 49):

If you want to change app language without restarting the app and also without any plugin, you can follow the bellow steps:

1. In main file of the application, change the default `MyHomePage` to a `StatefullWidget`, in `StatefullWedget` for example `MyHomePage` create a `static` method `setLocal` as follow

   ```
   class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
     MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) async {
         _MyHomePageState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyHomePageState>();
           state.changeLanguage(newLocale);
        }

     @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
   }
   ```

where `_MyHomePageState` is the `state` of your `MyHomePage` widget

2. In your `state` create a `static` method `changeLanguage`:

   ```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
     Locale _locale;

      changeLanguage(Locale locale) {
        setState(() {
         _locale = locale;
        });
       }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return MaterialApp(
           debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
           title: 'Afghanistan',
           theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue[800]),
           supportedLocales: [
             Locale('fa', 'IR'),
             Locale('en', 'US'),
             Locale('ps', 'AFG'),
           ],
           locale: _locale,
           localizationsDelegates: [
             AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
             GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
             GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
           ],
           localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
             for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
               if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                   supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                 return supportedLocale;
               }
             }
             return supportedLocales.first;
           },
           initialRoute: splashRoute,
           onGenerateRoute: Router.generatedRoute,
         );
      }
     }
   ```
3. Now from pages of your application you can change the language by calling the `setLocal` method and pass a new `Locale` as follow:

   ```
   Locale newLocale = Locale('ps', 'AFG');
   MyHomePage.setLocale(context, newLocale);
   ```
4. Please remember you need to create a `LocalizationDelegate`,
5. [Here](https://medium.com/@gs.sorush/flutter-localization-a39402757a42) is the link to the Written Tutorial and Demo Application

Comment: Looks like this tutorial/code needs updating for new Flutter changes.

Answer (score 9):

It's easier to use [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) package.

For changing language, for example:

```
onTap: (){
 EasyLocalization.of(context).locale = Locale('en', 'US'); 
}
```

I learned using this package by this video: [Youtube Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rgf278VJNI&t=6s)

**UPDATE:**

In version 3.0.0:

```
EasyLocalization.of(context).setLocale(Locale('en', ''));
```

Comment: This should be used with the latest version of easy localization (3.0.0)

EasyLocalization.of(context).setLocale(Locale('en', ''));

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the `MaterialApp` widget with a `ChangeNotifierProvider` and a `Consumer` widgets and control the language from the model.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => MainModel(context: context),
      child: Consumer<MainModel>(builder: (context, mainModel, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          locale: Locale(mainModel.preferredLanguageCode),
          ....
```

On the `MainModel`, all you need to do is change the `preferredLanguageCode` variable to whatever you want ('en', 'ar', 'es', etc). Don't forget to call `NotifyListeners()` once you change the language.

This and the other answer have only one problem: Any `context` above `MaterialApp` can't get the device language (for example when the app is started for the first time) with `Localizations.localeOf(context)`. This method required a `context` bellow `MaterialApp`.

To fix this issue, I used [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/devicelocale) to get the device language without the need of a `context`.

Once the app starts, you can change the language any way you want that this approach will work. I also use `SharedPreferences` to store the preferred language once the user changes it.

Comment: You can find code here for a full real world implementation of MultiProvider.  https://github.com/bksubhuti/buddhist_sun

Answer (score 1):

You can use the most popular [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get#change-locale) library as well.

Call `Get.updateLocale(locale)` to update the locale. Translations then automatically use the new locale.

```
var locale = Locale('en', 'US');
Get.updateLocale(locale);
```

Comment: Hey, I used a more traditional approach in app localization, and recently I used getx as my main state manager. So I tried for hours to make the localization works and I found this answer that solves my question. But can you tell that there is any specific way to change the text language as well without using `AppLocalizations.of(context)!;`

Answer (score 0):

For those who use the EasyLocalization Package, this is enough:

```dart
await context.setLocale(Locale('es')); // change `easy_localization` locale
```

An important thing to note for those who use GetX. If you use a GetMaterialApp instead of a MaterialApp, you need to refresh GetX after updating EasyLocalization:

```dart
final newLocale = Locale('es');
await context.setLocale(newLocale); // change `easy_localization` locale
Get.updateLocale(newLocale); // change `Get` locale direction
```