# how can i refresh application current screen after changing language in flutter?

Tags: flutter, internationalization

```
class ChangeLanguage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Change Language'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Change'),
          onPressed: () {
            navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

- I want to refresh previous screen according to the new language after pressing on raised button and calling navigator pop(context).
- I am using easy_localization 1.3.1 and when i navigate back to the previous screen the layout doesn't reversed

Comment: Your approach is might wrong. Because when you change the language it will affect all the screens globally no need to refresh the page. Please follow the standers and take a look at the documentation for the library which you are using it will help you out.

Comment: is that works for RTL approach and invert the layout from left to right to right to left because it works only for the translation not the layout widgets?

Comment: can you update the question which you have done till now. Or can you please help me with the plugin name if you're using for translation

Comment: I am using easy_localization 1.3.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a Flutter app language without restarting the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889889/how-to-change-a-flutter-app-language-without-restarting-the-app)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change app language without restarting the app and also without any plugin, you can follow the bellow steps:

1. In main file of the application, in `StatefullWedget` for example `MyHomePage` create a `static` method `setLocal` as follow

   ```
   class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
     MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale newLocale) async {
         _MyHomePageState state =
              context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyHomePageState>();());
           state.changeLanguage(newLocale);
        }

     @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
   }
   ```

where `_MyHomePageState` is the `state` of your `MyHomePage` widget

2. In your `state` create a `static` method `changeLanguage`:

   ```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
     Locale _locale;

      changeLanguage(Locale locale) {
        setState(() {
         _locale = locale;
        });
       }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return MaterialApp(
           debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
           title: 'Afghanistan',
           theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue[800]),
           supportedLocales: [
             Locale('fa', 'IR'),
             Locale('en', 'US'),
             Locale('ps', 'AFG'),
           ],
           locale: _locale,
           localizationsDelegates: [
             AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
             GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
             GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
           ],
           localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
             for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
               if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
                   supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                 return supportedLocale;
               }
             }
             return supportedLocales.first;
           },
           initialRoute: splashRoute,
           onGenerateRoute: Router.generatedRoute,
         );
      }
     }
   ```
3. Now from pages of your application you can change the language by calling the `setLocal` method and pass a new `Locale` as follow:

   ```
   Locale newLocale = Locale('ps', 'AFG');
   MyHomePage.setLocale(context, newLocale);
   ```

   4. Please remember you need to create a `LocalizationDelegate`,
   5. [Here](https://medium.com/@gs.sorush/flutter-localization-a39402757a42) is the link to the Written Tutorial and Demo Application

Comment: so, what about words translation, how can i translate words from predefind json files  according to the current locale ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added a link to a fully Functional Demo app, hope it will help you